CxFreeze msi not starting: Pandas error from xbbg
The following is the setup file for a simple .msi installer:
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000) 
#python setup.py bdist_msi
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "includes": ["tkinter", "win32timezone", "xbbg", "pandas", "numpy", "dask"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a 
# console application).
base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "Universe App",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Universe App",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("Universe App 2.0.py", base=base)]
)


After installing the app it throws the same error with xbbg every time.
Tried switching to a virtualenv but still no luck. I cant imagine there being a version clash as the libraries required are basic.
